# How to prevent void in output of list

Tags: list, scheme, racket, void

When I use `when` in list, `#<void>` come out quite often uncessarily. Following are examples for using map and for/list.

```
;; using map    
(define lst '(0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3))
    (map (lambda (x)
             (when (equal? 2 x)
                 x
                 ))
           lst)   
;; expected => '(2 2 2)
;; output => '(#<void>  #<void>  #<void>  #<void>  #<void>  #<void>
;; 2  2  2  #<void>  #<void>)

;; using for/list
    (define my-list '(0 0 0 1 2 1 2 2 2))
     (for/list ([a (drop-right my-list 1)]
                           [b (cdr lst)]
                           [i (in-naturals)])
                  (when (> a b)
                    (list a b i)))
;; expected => '(2 1 4)
;; output => '(#<void> #<void> #<void> #<void> (2 1 4) #<void> #<void> #<void>)
```

When I use `if` condition instead, I don't have anything else to put for `#false` state. How do I prevent those `#<void>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Renzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2382734) mentions, you can use `filter` if your goal is actually filtering. However, it’s worth also mentioning that you *can* use `for/list` for this by using a `#:when` clause in the loop:

```
(define lst '(0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3))
(define my-list '(0 0 0 1 2 1 2 2 2))

(for/list ([a (drop-right my-list 1)]
           [b (cdr lst)]
           [i (in-naturals)]
           #:when (> a b))
  (list a b i))

; => '((2 1 4))
```

Answer (score 4):

In these cases you should not use `map` or `for/list`: they apply the same operation to a list of objects and return a list obtained by consing **all the results of the application**. So, since `when` has no alternatives, when the condition is false the result is `#<void>`.

Use the predefined operator `filter` instead:

```
(filter (lambda (x) (equal? x 2)) '(0 0 0 1 2 1 2 2 2))
;; => '(2 2 2 2)
```